# How to redirect page to static file in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I redirect a page web request / request mapping in Spring Boot (MVC) to point to a static file (example:   .txt, .json, .jpg, .mp4, etc). All I have in my Spring Boot project is an application.properties file and the @Controllers.

I'd like for the user, when making a web request to the url in browser to be asked to download the file (not use it to attempt to render the page, like it does with .html, .jsp)

Comment: Download a file when user clicks a link ? Is that you mean by `redirecting to static file` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achive this by telling the response that you wish to attach a downloadable file. Then you can simple write the content you want to make downloadable.

Here is an example :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/myredirect", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Remove this instruction if you wish to disable the download dialog.
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.ext");

    // Load your file content as byte.
    byte[] fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(new ClasspathResource("myfile").getIntputStream());

    response.getOutputStream().write(fileContent);
}
```

On the other hand, if you simply want a direct mapping to a static file. You may use the default `public` folder of Spring Boot Starter Web.

Any file found inside `classpath:/public` will be mapped to `/*`by default.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had a question. Right now, I can access my static file by going to the root path (ex: www.mysite.com/myfile.txt) but I'd like to be able to access the same file at something like (www.mysite.com/myredirect) .... how can I configure the project to map a request to redirect to the static file?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my snippet to answer your question. You need to define your redirect url from the RequestMapping value. Then load your file as an byte array from the classpath or an absolute path. As you wish. Good luck. If you wish to remove the download behavior, just remove the setHeader snipper.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out!

Comment: I've been reading your comment again and I think you didn't understood that any resource available in the public folder of your classpath will be available from the root path.

Ex : file in `public/img/logo.png` would be available from the url `www.mysite.com/img/logo.png`. If you prefer having a custom URL, then the request mapping is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect using the "redirect:" prefix in Spring. From the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix):

> A logical view name such as redirect:/myapp/some/resource will redirect relative to the current Servlet context, while a name such as redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path will redirect to an absolute URL.

An example would be:

```
@RequestMapping("/redirectToResource")
protected String redirect(@RequestParameter("resource") String resource) {
    return "redirect:/myapp/some/" + resource;
}
```

You can place static resources to be served directly in your classpath in any of the following locations (see [Serving static resources](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)):

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
    "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but using "redirect:" would result in a rewrite of the url the end user reached. I'm not sure this behavior is desired. It also limits to serving resources that are already available as static resources.

Comment: Yes, it results in a browser redirect. To load a file dynamically you could always take in a @RequestParameter as a method parameter. And yes, the file is served as a static resource by Spring Boot.